# Laplace functional for given process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value

Consider $X_{1} \dots $ *i.r.v* with $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution. Let's consider $S_n = X_{1} + \dots + X_{n}$.

So we may construct a point process $Y = \{Y(B) = \sum \mathbb{1}_{B}(S_n) , B\in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$.

No we need to find $\mathfrak{L}(f) = \mathbb{E}(\exp[-\sum_n f(S_n)])$,

My attempt :

First of all let's suppose that we have $\xi $~$Gamma(n,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ , when $\mathbb{E}(\exp[-s\xi]) = \left(\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda + s}\right)^n$.

Let's consider $f = \sum_{k = 1}^{m} a_k\mathbb{1}_{B_k}$, hence we have :

$\mathfrak{L}(f) = \mathbb{E}\exp[-\sum_{n}^{\infty} \sum_k^{m} a_{k} \mathbb{1}_{B_k}(S_n)]$ replace sum sign due to positive terms.

$\mathfrak{L}(f) = \prod \mathbb{E} \exp[-a_k Y(B_{k})]$, but there is the stuck problem.

What should I do now?

Comment: What is the domain of f? Is it a generic measurable real function? And where the definition of Y enters in the question?

Comment: @Thomas $f$ should be a Borel-function

Comment: @Thomas I mean Borel-measurable function

Comment: Thx. What role instead plays Y? It seems that it is not necessary to define the laplace functional? I am asking to be sure that I am getting the problem...

Comment: @Thomas Y is a point process.